# How can I expand data frame from aggregated table

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have following table.

```
> as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
      Admit Gender Dept Freq
1  Admitted   Male    A  512
2  Rejected   Male    A  313
3  Admitted Female    A   89
4  Rejected Female    A   19
5  Admitted   Male    B  353
6  Rejected   Male    B  207
7  Admitted Female    B   17
8  Rejected Female    B    8
9  Admitted   Male    C  120
10 Rejected   Male    C  205
11 Admitted Female    C  202
12 Rejected Female    C  391
13 Admitted   Male    D  138
14 Rejected   Male    D  279
15 Admitted Female    D  131
16 Rejected Female    D  244
17 Admitted   Male    E   53
18 Rejected   Male    E  138
19 Admitted Female    E   94
20 Rejected Female    E  299
21 Admitted   Male    F   22
22 Rejected   Male    F  351
23 Admitted Female    F   24
24 Rejected Female    F  317
```

How can I expand them? **Expand means I want to have all the original rows before the Freq count**. For example, the first row in aggregated table will be expanded into `512` rows. All of them have the same 3 values `Admitted`, `Male` and `Dept`.

I am thinking about using many `rep` and `rbind`, but seems not effective. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can generate a replication index `ind`:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
ind <- rep.int(1:nrow(dat), dat$Freq)
```

Then we can replicate rows of `dat` with this `ind`:

```
dat[ind, 1:3]  ## you want the first 3 columns
```